# Proof of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n(n!)} = \int_0^1\frac{e^x-1}{x}dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

I want to prove that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n\cdot n!} = \int_0^1\frac{e^x-1}{x} \,dx.$$

I tried this:
$$g(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{e^x-1}{x} , x\neq0\\
1,x=0\\
\end{cases}$$

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$, so $g(x)$ is continuous in $[0,1]$. Therfore $$(1)\int_0^1g(x)dx=\int_0^1\frac{e^x-1}{x}dx$$
Next, 
$$e^x-1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
And this series converges uniformly in $[0,1]$. If $0\lt x\le1$ divide by $x$:
$$\Rightarrow(2)\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}$$
In addition,
$$(3)\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{0^{n-1}}{n!}=0^0=1$$
From $(2),(3)$ we can conclude that for every $x\in[0,1]$:
$$(4)g(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!}$$
This series converges uniformly in $[0,1]$, so from $(1),(4)$:
$$\int_0^1\frac{e^x-1}{x} \, dx = \int_0^1 g(x) \, dx =\int_0^1\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{n!} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^1 \frac{x^{n-1}}{n!} =\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n\cdot n!}$$
I'm not so sure that all the steps i took in my proof are 100% correct,

Comment: I guess your proof is correct. You made the main substitution and check the last part.

Comment: the proof is correctn only the step (3) is not necessary (for x=0, g have a false singularity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You proof looks basically correct to me.

- $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$  should be $\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=1$.
- I would write (1) as
  $$(1)\int_0^1\frac{e^x-1}{x}dx=\int_0^1g(x)dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

As a generalization,
if we subtract
the first $m$ terms
of the series for
$e^x$
and divide by $x^m$,
we get this:

$f_m(x)
=e^x-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} \dfrac{x^k}{k!}
=
$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\int_0^1 \dfrac{f_m(x)dx}{x^m}
&=\int_0^1 \dfrac{\sum_{k=m}^{\infty} \dfrac{x^k}{k!}dx}{x^m}\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^{\infty} \dfrac1{k!}\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^kdx}{x^m}\\
&=\sum_{k=m}^{\infty} \dfrac1{k!}\int_0^1 x^{k-m}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac1{(k+m)!}\int_0^1 x^{k}dx\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \dfrac1{(k+1)(k+m)!}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \dfrac1{k(k+m-1)!}\\
\end{array}
$

This problem is
the case $m=1$.